# Using modulus in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, modulo

I am trying to understand how to repeat loops using the mod operator.

If you have two strings, `"abc"` and `"defgh"`, how can `%` be used to loop through `abc`, repeating it until the end of `defgh` is reached?  Namely, what is the mod relationship of the length of `abc` and `defgh`?

I don't really understand this concept.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Note for everyone, this is a continuation of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507600/repeating-loop-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple.

```
std::string abc("abc");
std::string defgh("defgh");

for (size_t i = 0; i < defgh.length(); ++i)
{
    printf("%c", abc[i % abc.length()]);
}
```

Think about what the Modulus operator is doing, it discretely divides the left hand side by the right hand side, and spits back the integer remainder.

Example:

```
0 % 3 == 0
1 % 3 == 1
2 % 3 == 2
3 % 3 == 0
4 % 3 == 1
```

In our case, the left hand side represents the i'th position in "defgh", the right hand represents the length of "abc", and the result the looping index inside "abc".

Comment: As if the concepts change anyway; he might as well figure out how to convert it to C...

Answer (score 3):

The typical usage of `mod` is for generating values inside a fixed range. In this case, you want values that are between 0 and `strlen("abc")-1` so that you don't access a position outside `"abc"`.

The general concept you need to keep in mind is that `x % N` will always return a value between `0` and `N-1`. In this particular case, we also take advantage of the fact that if you increase `x` by 1 `x % N` also increases by 1. See it?

Another important property of modulus that we use here is the fact that it "rolls over". As you increase `x` by 1, `x % N` increases by 1. When it hits `N-1`, the next value will be `0`, and so on.

Look at @Daniel's code. It's C++ but the concept is language-agnostic